# How to numerically solve this nonlinear differential equation with partial initial boundary condition and partial terminal boundary condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, boundary-value-problem, nonlinear-dynamics

Let the two states be $\lambda:[0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ and $p:[0,T]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{++}$. $b$ is a constant which is positive.

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\dot{\lambda} &=-\frac{b}{\lambda}\log (pb) \\ 
\dot{p} &=[\frac{1}{\lambda^2}-\frac{\log (pb)}{\lambda^2}]pb
\end{align}
$$
with $\lambda(0)=\lambda_0>0$ and $p(T)=p_T>0$.

How to numerically solve this nonlinear differential equations with the boundary conditions mentioned above? Sorry if there is any misuse of terms. It would be great if you guys can provide some materials about how to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: What is $p_T$?? Also, why you assume the solution $p(T)$ is a constant value?

Comment: This differential equation is derived when I solve an optimal control problem. Actually, $p$ is the costate. $p_T$ is a constant dependent on the terminal cost.

Comment: I never had a problem like this. For boundary value problem, collocation methods are sometimes useful. i.e. you represent $\lambda$ and $p$ for example as a polynomial $\lambda = \sum_k a_k t^k$ or better as a B-Spline. The you can compute the derivatives of your numerical trial function exactly and this yields a system of equations like $\dot \lambda(t_j) = \sum_k a_k k t_j^{k-1} = f(t_j)$. In your case it would be nonlinear. Another class of methods are shooting methods, where you try to optimize the initial conditions such that the terminal values is hit.

Comment: You can guess $p(0)$ evolve the ODE and read off $p(T)$. Then adjust the guess untill $p(T) = p_T$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method